# How to have a WCF Service project use DataContractSerialzer instead of XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

We are doing enhancements to a WCF service application. This WCF service application references another WCF service. Enhancements are done to both WCF service applications. Therefore I am updating the service reference whenever there are changes. I am observing strange behavior when VS 2010 is generating client proxy classes. Whenever an update happens, VS 2010 is using the `XMLSerializer`. Earlier it was using the `DataContractSerializer`.

But when I created an empty WCF Service application and referenced another WCF service, the `DataContractSerializer` is being used.

I want to update service reference using `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XMLSerializer`. Otherwise I have to change a lot of code, since I have to update code for the `PropertySpecified` field as well.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Search your service side code to see if [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute was added to your service.  That's really the only way this could happen, unless of course, you're specifically setting the flag during client proxy generation to use XmlSerializer.

If that doesn't work, then you may want to consider just deleting your service reference and re-adding it.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. Checked code for attribute it is not present. Wondering how VS 2010 decides to use different serializers for different projects when generating proxy code.